# What does Islam say about Aurora Borealis / Northern Lights?

Tags: hadith, islamic-philosophy, judaism

Are there any Sahih Hadith or any other reference from Yahudi sources?

Comment: is there a special reason you are asking?

Comment: Why would Islam say anything about Aurora Borealis?

Comment: @Kilise This post made me ponder over it: https://www.ummah.com/forum/forum/general/the-lounge/377150-aurora-northern-lights-are-really-jinn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mention of aurora borealis in Islam, neither in the Qur'an nor in the Sunnah.

Comment: Thanks ... do we have anything from Jewish sources?

Comment: @Ahmed, none that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Narrated Abdullah: Regarding the Verse: "Indeed he (Muhammad) did see. Of the Signs of his Lord, The Greatest!" (53.18) That the Prophet had seen a green carpet spread all over the horizon of the sky.  ([Book #59, Hadith #44](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3233))

Comment: An evidence is hardlky an answer please elaborate!

Answer (score 1):

assalam o alikum in sahih al bukahari volume 4 hadith 456 it is written that the prophet have seen green carpet spread all over the night time. if u see green carpet and nights sky it is saying that green lights occurred in night time. means green lights as aurora and in night time

thanks for asking
hadith number 456 volume 4 allah hafiz

have good day